# Can a Chinese citizen apply for a Korean visa in Jeju Island?

Tags: visas, south-korea, chinese-citizens, jeju

Jeju Island is visa-free for Chinese nationals. Is it possible for Chinese nationals to apply for a visa for the Korean mainland from Jeju Island? I have searched around but cannot find anything specific.

Comment: Korea itself is visa free for many nationalities. Worth posting your nationality, because there are about 180 different ones.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks, I’ve updated my question.

Answer (score 4):

A Korean visa cannot be issued on South Korean soil. A visa can only be issued by a Consulate, according to [Immigration Guide - Visa](https://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?catSeq=382&categoryId=2&parentId=382&showMenuId=374). Therefore you will need to take care of the visa before you land in Jeju Island.